# Do each application within one App pool get unloaded in IIS 7.X

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, application-pools

Do each application within one App pool get unloaded in IIS 7.X or does it affect the  whole app pool?

if i have one hundred applications under same app pool are alls of the applications always loaded?

Answer (score 3):

Loaded or unloaded?

All applications within the same App Pool may run as part of the same worker process.

So a crash in any one of those applications will take them all out at the same time (at least for as long as it takes to start a new worker process and serve a request).

Second part: If you have 100 applications in a pool, they're always considered part of that pool, but demand-start behaviour might apply - ASP templates might not be compiled until called, .Net code won't be exercised until a particular function is run, and so on.